# Backend server for Android clients - Possible to verify that the customer has bought the application?

Tags: android

Scenario: Server providing a rest-api to Android clients. There are no subscriptions involved, but customers have to pay for the application in order to get access to the rest-service.

Does Google offer an API the back-end server can use to query Google whether the given client has paid for the application? Perhaps by forwarding an installation / purchase id from the client?

Answer (score 1):

When you publish an android app on GooglePlay if it's a paid app you can use inside your code [LVL](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html) library as external jar that allows you verify the license.